# Delete all information you don't need in notepad++ and then put it on separate lines

Tags: notepad++

I want to know how to take a large amount of code and then remove all of the useless stuff that I dont need.

For example, take

```
<option value="S1">blah blah blah</option> <option value="s2">blah blah blah</option>
```

and turn it into just

```
Blah blah blah
blah blah blah
```

I know how to get rid of the `</option>` Quite easily, but i don't know a easy way to get rid of the `<option value="different value each time">`

Also, is it possible to put each value on its own line once the `<option value='different value each time">` has been removed? So i do not have to go through hundreds of lines pressing enter?

Answer (score 2):

#### I want to remove all of the useless stuff that I  dont need

> I know how to get rid of the `</option>` quite easily, but I don't know an easy way to get rid of the `<option value="different value each time">`.
>
> Also, is it possible to put each value on its own line once the `<option value='different value each time">` has been removed?

- Menu "Search" > "Replace" (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>)
- Set "Find what" to `[\<]option value.*?[\>](.*?)[\<]/option[\>] ?`
- Set "Replace with" to `\1\r\n`
- Enable "Regular expression"
- Click "Replace All"

  [image]

**Before**:

```
<option value="S1">blah blah blah 1</option> <option value="s2">blah blah blah 2</option>
```

**After**:

```
blah blah blah 1
blah blah blah 2
```

Notes:

- The above assumes you are editing a text file with Windows EOLs, `\r\n`.
- If you are using files with different EOLs you can convert them to Windows EOLs using Menu "Edit" > "EOL Conversion".
- If you aren't working with Windows EOL, and you don't wish to convert them, use the following instead:

  - Use `\n` instead of `\r\n` for Unix/OS X EOLs
  - Use `\r` instead of `\r\n` for Mac OS (up to version 9) EOLs

---

#### Further reading

- [Notepad++: A guide to using regular expressions and extended search mode](http://markantoniou.blogspot.co.uk/2008/06/notepad-how-to-use-regular-expressions.html)